# Why is current location different between Google Maps and the Location Services API?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-location-services

The blue icon which represents the current location in the map is different from the location I get from the Location Services API.

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(new CustomConnectionCallbacks())
        .build();

locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
    googleApiClient, 
    locationRequest, 
    new CustomLocationListener()
);
```

I'm trying to put a marker exactly where the user is located, but when I use the last known location from the Location Services API, the marker is in a different position 25% of the times.

Is Google Maps using the Google Location Services API? Am I using the right configuration?